# CSS3 to target first text letter of first X element?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm currently using this selector:

```
.entry > p:first-of-type:first-letter {
}
```

To do a drop cap for the first letter of the first P element under .entry.

It works fine on [this page](http://www.mossoreviews.com/8-amazon-kindle-fire-review/), but not [this one](http://www.mossoreviews.com/16-asus-a53z-as61-15-6-inch-laptop-review/). The problem with the latter one is probably because there's an <a> element proceeding all the text content inside the first P element.

So my question is how to work around this? How to target the first **text** letter of the first X element rather than just the first letter?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that's possible currently. CSS3's letter selector is very limited.

Comment: What's going to happen to this question now that you've changed your page source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your second page is that the first `<p>` has nothing but an image in it. Your text doesn't start until the second `<p>`.

If you remove the `<p>` around the image, then the text "At $499.." will be in the first `<p>` and the letter "A" will match the CSS selector you have.